# How to Shutdown PC by Pressing Power Button without asking confirmations?

Tags: windows-7, reset, shutdown

I always Hibernate my PC. Sometimes when I boot, it does not recognize the mouse/keyboard or any USB devices. I've also setup it to go in sleep in 5 minutes.

In that case I can't restart the PC so that USB starts working.

When I press the Power button then it starts shutdown but asks confirmation twice, one is for shutdown by force confirmation and then there is one more. When my USB is disabled I can't input these options. So I switch off the power.

**What I want is that upon pressing Power Button it should at once start shutdown without asking any more confirmations**

System details:
Win-7 Home Premium 64 bit
Intel i3 530
Asus P montherboard
**EDIT:** It is Desktop PC

Comment: http://www.trishtech.com/win7/turn_off_auto_termination_of_programs_in_windows_7.php     look at that link, I'd read it more thoroughly and post an answer but I'm tired. Hope it helps. Alternatively, use the `shutdown /s /t 0` command in the Command Prompt.

Comment: first the link is not working. Second I want to shutdown by pressing my power button when mouse/kw are disabled.

Comment: Have the remote desktop service active and log in from another system via the network.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it easily just you have to the following steps. Go to the start menu and click on **Control Panel** now select the **Power Option**. After this select the **Change Plan Settings**

[image]

Now another window will come over and now you have to select the option **Change Advance Power Setting**

[image]

Now a small window pops up and scroll down to find the option **Power Button and Lid** and click on `+` sigh to expand it. Now you will see the option **Power button action** and clcik the `+` to expand it.

[image]

Now select the option **Shut Down** for `On battery` and `Plug In` and click apply. Now whenever you press the power button computer will shutdown. But still one problem how to power off without force it. Now copy and paste the following keys in notepad and save it with the name of `shutdown.reg`.

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SessionManager\Memory Management]
"ClearPageFileAtShutdown"=dword:00000001 

[HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Desktop]
"AutoEndTasks"="1"  

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control]
"WaitToKillServiceTimeout"="1000"
```

After saving it on disk just double click on it to add to registry. Windows will ask you to confirm just press the OK button every time and you are on the way. It will shutdown the windows without asking you to force shutdown.

**Note:**  This will always shut down Windows, even if an application is open with unsaved changes.

Comment: I'll check it tonight

Comment: I've put this code in .reg file but while installing it it's showing error: ------ "The specfied file is not a registry script. You can only import binary registery files from within the registry editor".  -------    Can you please try in your PC if it's able to install?

Comment: @AgA updated the keys now copy and paste them again in notepad and run them.

Comment: No still it does not work. Yesterday I manually fed AutoEndTasks and WaitToKillServiceTimeout in registry but it did not do anything on pressing power button. I request you to check it at your end.

Comment: I've another useful link: http://infodotnet.blogspot.in/2008/10/windows-xp-shutdown-faster-by-enabling.html  seem to have worked and it shutdown immediately. We don't need to clear the page file - it is for security reasons.

Comment: Ah! I see I forget to mention about the `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop] "AutoEndTasks"="1"`. Glad you find that too. And its completely depend on you if you don't want to clear the page file or not. :)

Comment: @AGA, add `REGEDIT4` to the top of the file.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds to me like you may want to check some BIOS settings with regard to ACPI. I suggest "S3" and possibly enable legacy USB support too. Then make sure your power supply has enough current on the 5V rails for when your system goes to sleep or hibernates. Check your mobo specs as well since you may need to set a jumper/switch to enable power control from a USB device like a keyboard or mouse. But if it's a laptop then there's probably nothing you can do with power supplies or physical switch settings. However, you may want to look at your Windows power settings (powercfg.cpl) to adjust any settings there too.

It's hard to guess what's going on. But I'd be willing to bet that some simple BIOS adjustments may be all that's necessary. Please don't confuse this with the much more dangerous BIOS "update" or "flash" procedure either. I'm only talking about BIOS settings which should easily be accessible when powering up your computer - usually by pressing the DEL key.

Comment: Please see most of time my PC runs fine but since last 1 month little more of problems due to this. Why are you talking about USB legacy support?